# Print dropdown selected value into a label after button click

Tags: powerapps

I am new to the power app. I have created a screen. On my screen, there is a **Dropdown Control**. Dropdown control is populated values with the below code:

```
Table({Text: "Bangladesh", Val: 1},{Text: "India", Val: 2},{Text: "Pakistan", Val: 3 })
```

I have a button and Label. Now I want when the user clicks on the button the selected value of the dropdown will be printed on the label. I used the below code for the **OnSelect** property of the button

```
Label2.Text = Dropdown1.Selected.Text
```

But nothing happens. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly assign a component property from outside this component

I suggest you to use a variable to store your DropDown1 selected value on the button OnSelect property, and then assign your variable on your Label2 Text property, here are the formulas :

```
[Button] OnSelect : Set(varValue, DropDown1.Selected.Text)
[Label2] Text : varValue
```

Have a good day